# how to resolve this particular issue?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am doing an app using Django anf python. My web page have to parts. Left parts are for navigation using ajax which brings some data to the right one.On clicking the right side 
it leads to the different URLs.

My url patters are:

```
foo.com/main/
foo.com/main/a/
foo.com/main/a/b/
foo.com/main/a/b/c/
```

When ever I click on the right side it makes an ajax call to bring data. But the URL remains same of the previous one. So, I decided to use #!.

But My problem is:
Suppose I am on URL `foo.com/main/a/b/` But after ajax call I want the URL to be
`foo.com/main/#!/1/`  So, What ever Page I am If i made a ajax call the URL should be

```
foo.com/main/#!/1/
```

Is it possible? How?

Thanks

Comment: You can also ditch hashbangs and use `history.pushState()` (http://diveintohtml5.org/history.html#illusion), it will fall back to normal non-ajax behaviour for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is not going to change the URL because it doesn't cause a page reload (which is the point of using AJAX). You can change the URL using window.location.href but that will cause the browser to attempt a get from the URL specified. I looked it up and there is some indications that some browsers allow you to change the URL in the address bar without reloading the page but I wouldn't count on that functionality. (ie if it exists it is very dangerous (spoofing, phishing) and will likely be disabled or altered imo)

Answer (score 0):

This is much more an ajax question than a Django question, but okay.  You want there to be a mapping between your hash-bang (#!) URLs within the client portion of your code, and the URLs defined on the Django side.

I recommend that you look for an Ajax framework that will help you with this.  Popular ones include Sammy.js, Spine.js, and (my preference) [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/).  These help you define a regular mapping between client-side hash-based urls and back-end URLs that access the data via Ajax.  I like Backbone because it's very precise in its relationships between datasets coming from the server, their access URLs (the URL you use to make Ajax calls), their display URLs (the hash-bang URL shown on the page), and defining a single method per data item for translating between the two URLs.

Comment: Can you go deeper .. I read the sammy.js but I could not find out the way to resolve my problem ..

Answer (score 0):

You might have to do what sites like google maps use to enable linking to ajax-rich pages. They have a "permalink" which has all the parameters in the url. Then if a user later goes to that link then the server knows how to set the page up. Check out how google maps does it for more info. The actual document url as seen in the browser window doesn't change. If its good enough for google, then its good enough for the rest of us.